# Where can I find the JDK 1.5 source code?

Tags: java, java-5

Where can I find the entire source code for JDK 1.5 to download? I am unable to find the exact link on the oracle site; the link provided only goes in circles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name Java can be applied to many different components that work together.  It might mean the "Java Virtual Machine" to some, the "Java Language Specification" to others, "Java compilers" to many, and "Java language libraries" to quite a few.

If you want the source code to the Java virtual machine (JVM) for Java5, [it is available](http://java.sun.com/j2se/jrl_download.html); but, not under an open source license.  The first "open source" copy of Java was released with "Java 6".  If you want Java5 source code, you needed to sign up for a "Java Researcher License Agreement" which provided you access to the source code for the JVM for (at least Java5).  Having the source code of the JVM is completely unnecessary in writing code for the Java5 environment.

If you want the source code for the Java Language Specification for Java5, [it is a text document (typically published as a book or on-line set of web pages)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html).  While it might allow you to understand if a compiler should complain with an error under certain circumstances, again it is not necessary to write a program for the Java5 environment.

If you want the Java5 compiler, [it can be downloaded in the oracle archives of old releases of the Java development toolkit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html).  If you want write a program for Java5, downloading and using this offering is generally best-practice for developing Java5 programs.  Alternatively you may configured a compatible compatible compiler (Java6 / Java7) to emit Java5 code.

If you want the Java5 language libraries, they are included with the Java5 development kit.  The Java6 and Java7 development kit offerings provide language libraries that go to great efforts to be compatible with Java5 source code; however, newer libraries also include newer features and operations which a stock Java5 virtual machine will not be able to reference.  Again, there are techniques to safely use a backwards-compatible version of Java (6/7); however, one doesn't need to apply any extra care if they base their development off a Java5 development kit.  The "source code" for the language libraries was included in the source code for the JVM under the Java Research License Agreement, to the degree that SUN was allowed to include such source code.

While SUN has licensed a number of technologies from other companies in a manner where they can be freely distributed with Java5, SUN did not necessarily own all of the technologies in Java5 outright.  As such, even under the Java Researcher License Agreement, some of the source code is not available (although the compiled libraries are).  Open source projects (like OpenJDK) were quick to implement these missing "holes" with open-source libraries to get a fully functional open-source Java stack; but, that is Java6+ (not Java5).

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response, i am just an amateur who would like to see the source for the java.lang and other basic packages to quench my curiosity.. should i check the java archives? :)!!

Comment: If you just want to see source for the "java.lang" stuff, look to Java6.  At least is is available without a restrictive license.  Also, realize that most of it is written in Java, with a number of key "native" backings.  You need to know your JNI to read it, and the native implementation is really dependent on the JVM implementation.  These areas of the code deal with things that must be done, but are not exposed in the language (like malloc'ing memory and registering classes in a manner that allows automatic garbage collection).  Interesting stuff; rarely useful to the typical project.

Answer (score 1):

Java 1.5 is not open source. Quoting Wikipedia:

> On November 13, 2006, Sun released much of Java as free and open source software, (FOSS), under the terms of the GNU General Public License (GPL). On May 8, 2007, Sun finished the process, making all of Java's core code available under free software/open-source distribution terms, aside from a small portion of code to which Sun did not hold the copyright.

As far as I can remember it was possible to get the source code for research purposes (our university had access to the source code with a special agreement with Sun) but I don't think that it will be possible to get it from Oracle.

Before the open sourcing there were several free implementation of the JVM and of the core classes. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Java_implementations for examples.

Answer (score 0):

visit the 
[oracle archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html)

Comment: i dont see the source code in this link only the binaries...

Comment: All the source you can get is in the JDK.

Comment: Don't forget Java 5.0 is so old it was End Of Life'd before Oracle bought Sun. It also pre-dates the OpenJDK so the only source available is in the JDK.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The JDK does not contain the sources. Java was not open source before 2006.

Comment: So i need to download the jdk for the source code?? when i check it i see that it asks me to save an .exe file..is this correct? can't i get a link to download only the source files may be like a zip or something?

Comment: @Matteo and yet its has always has a `src.zip` file which contains the source to most of the JRE.

Comment: @hakish Not as far as I know.  You also have to install it.  If you don't want to install the JDK why do you need a copy of the source?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes but it contains the source code for the core classes not the sources of the JDK itself (JVM, compiler, ..)

Comment: The JDK is not the same as the JVM.

Comment: @Matteo, the package he wants to look into `java.lang` might have the Java-side source in `src.zip`; but, all the interesting stuff in that package is in the `native` methods.  `src.zip` fails to pack up any non-Java code, and I'm not sure if it was even available back in Java5.  And as you said, that _also_ doesn't include source for executables like javac, javap, java, etc.

Comment: Since the OP hasn't said why he wants this or which part of the source he needs, it not clear if `src.zip` would ahve what he wants or not.  I would say that a lot of work has gone into making OpenJDK 7 in particular easier to build.  If he had the full source for Java 5.0 it would be very difficult to build even for the JVM developers at Oracle (as most were JRockIt developers)